# Defining Internal Energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

The first law of Thermodynamics is $$ dU = dQ - dW $$ Halliday and Resnick says that energy transfer of heat Q $\text{occurs to the system}$ (which is by convention positive) and a Work W is done $\text{by the system}$ (which is by convention again is positive). this total energy transfer is the internal energy so shouldn't internal energy U be defined Q + W rather than Q - W.

Please let me know why is it defined Q - W whereas in chemistry it is defined as Q + W?

The above conventions are mentioned in Halliday Resnick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention for the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC) is the Kelvin form

$dU = \delta q + \delta w$

Heat eXits the system in an eXothermic process (and eNters in an eNdothermic process). Work eXits the system when it is done *by* the system. In either case (heat or work), exiting values are negative.

The convention for engineering is the Clausius form (which was the first statement of the first law)

$dU = \delta q - \delta w$

The same conventions apply for heat (negative for exothermic processes, positive for endothermic processes). For engineers, work done *by* the system has utility for us and is given a positive sign.

Both forms are [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics)

Answer (score 4):

> Please let me know why is it defined Q - W whereas in chemistry it is
> defined as Q + W?

It's simply a matter of convention.

The sign of $Q$ is the same for both, with the sign for $W$ reversed. In the version $\Delta U=Q-W$ work done by the system is considered positive whereas in $\Delta U=Q+W$ the work done by the system is negative. But since, in the absence of heat, when a system does work its internal energy decreases, both versions are consistent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Halliday and Resnick is not, in my opinion, a good book. There are many editions, and most of them have egregious errors that are corrected in the next edition, while  new errors are added.

I don't know what they say here, but work done by the system can be  positive or  negative. When work *done by* the system is positive the system  looses energy. Similarly the heat *added to* the system can be both positive or negative. When it is postive the system gains energy.

Note that Chemists and Physicics have opposite sign conventions. For physicists $Q$ is postive when the system *gains* energy, and for chemists $Q$ is postive when the system *looses* energy to the outside world (an exothermic reaction for example).

Comment: Can you please tell me the correct conventions?

Comment: Do you know good books where I can get correct information

Comment: Are you chemist or a physicist?

Comment: science student I must learn according to the subject

Comment: But please tell me for physics only

Comment: For physics, *Q* is posive for head added, so $\Delta U =Q-W$... Using "$dQ$" and "$dW$" is bad notation as $Q$ and $W$ qre not functions of the system's state.

Comment: How about convention for work is it work by the system negative and work done on the system positive? for physics?

Comment: For a small change in volume  $PdV$ is the work done *by the system*, so when $PdV$ is positve the system is giving energy to the outside world and the change in *internal* energy $dU$ is negative. Hence $dU=-PdV$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134757/discussion-between-shashaank-and-mike-stone).

Comment: Check out https://openstax.org/

Comment: @Shashaank If it is a convention, there is no *correct* convention. Conventions may be more or less useful, but never right or wrong.

Comment: It is not true that Physicists have a uniform convention about the meaning of $Q$ and $W$, and then about the signs. I would consider Max Planck as a physicist. In its Tretease on Thermodynamics, he wrote the first principle as $\Delta U = Q+W$. I would say that physicists oscillate between the engineering and chemistry conventions.

Comment: @Shashaank Both versions are correct because they both correctly account for the effect of the work done on or by the system on the change in internal energy.